# facebook apps settings opengraph dashboard not updating

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I asked a similar question earlier, but it was one of a bunch of questions, most of which I later solved. So I figured I would create a new question only about this.

In developers.facebook => $MY_APP => app settings => open graph => dashboard, you have options to manage your actions and objects. When I try to edit an action, for example by changing its name, or the object reference it points to, these changes wil ostensibly be saved, but when I refresh the page, it will not have the changes (for the object reference) or the url for the object will not change (for changing the action name).

For example,

When I change the name of action1 to action2, from "get code" the page will still be
https://graph.facebook.com/me/myapp:$action1

Furthermore, calling myapp:$action2 will not work, and when I call myapp:$action1 the action that shows up in my timeline is still $action1.

I may also wish to change the title of my object, from say title1 to title2. However, when I try to change the action so that the reference is to title2, the changes refuse to save.

Is there a solution to this, or should I just delete everything and start anew without making mistakes? I tried deleting the actions and objects and making new ones with the old names, but the moment a make an action with the old name all the old fields are filled out and I can't change them again.

Thanks.

EDIT: to change url and name stuff, those are in advanced options inside the action type edit page. Thanks Paul for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph api name is in the Advanced section of the ActionType edit page.

For your second question, I don't really understand why your Object Type name won't change. Do you mean the value of `og:type` isn't changing or the "Name" field? The second one is also in advanced.

Comment: Hi, about 5 seconds before I saw your post I noticed the advanced section for the first time. What's not changing is in ActionType edit page, the action properties subsection, where it lists the connected object type and then the reference it points to.

Comment: oh yeah... that is a hard problem. Try removing the connected object, saving it (connect to something else if you need to), then putting it back. Sorry about that :( I should really go work on that instead of answering questions here :)

Comment: Heh, I just read your profile, and realized why you seem to be so familiar with the new features. Thanks by the way, open graph is really a cool feature.